# Integrand that is divergent at some points

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have a function $f(x)$ where it has a singularity at the point $x=10$.

$$f(x) = \frac{-1}{g(x) \sqrt{1 - \frac{a^6 g(x)}{x^6 g(a)}}}, \qquad g(x) = 1 - \Big(\frac{x}{h}\Big)^4, \qquad a=13.128, \; h=10.$$

The singularity at $x=10$ is manageable. As you approach the point from the left you approach $-\infty$, while if you approach the point from the right you approach $\infty$. But if you consider both infinities by taking the limit from both sides ($10-\epsilon,10+\epsilon$) you approach a finite number which says that the integral in that region must be finite.

$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0} \Big(f(10-\epsilon) + f(10+\epsilon)\Big) \approx 1.84817.$$

My main goal is to take the integral of $f(x)$ from $[0,13.128]$.

$$\int_0^{13.128} f(x) dx$$

[image]

---

The question is, I don't know how to write the code to make the positive infinite discontinuity and negative infinite discontinuity at $x=10$ compensate each other so as to make the integral finite in that region knowing that the limit as you approach $x=10$ on both sides is finite,

```
Limit[f[10 - e] + f[10 + e], e -> 0]
1.84817
```

Comment: I think [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html) could help you, in particular [the part on principal values](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#295594003).

Comment: $\int_a^b {1 \over (x-a)^p}\,dx$ is a convergent *improper integral* for $0<p<1$. ($p=1/2$ in your case, no?) This is discussed in any single-variable calculus textbook, I think.

Comment: @LukasLang I've read that part but I guess what I want to know is how to do it manually in mathematica instead of using `Method->PrincipalValue`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Right, I've edited my post. Thanks!

Comment: @mathemania what part exactly do you want to do manually? The entire integration? Only the limt? Something else? And why not just use thr built-in solution?

Comment: It would help to have the definitions as Mathematica code.

Comment: @LukasLang I wanted to know how to apply the Cauchy principal value manually to get a finite integral.

Comment: To approximate $\int_a^b {f(x) \over x-c}\,dx$, find $\int_a^{c-\delta} {f(x) \over x-c}\,dx + \int_{c+\delta}^b  {f(x) \over x-c}\,dx$ and add $\int_{c-\delta/2^k} ^{c-\delta/2^{k+1}} {f(x) \over x-c}\,dx + \int_{c+\delta/2^{k+1}}^{c+\delta/2^k} {f(x) \over x-c}\,dx$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots$ until you feel it's sufficiently converged (e.g. added value is $<10^{-6}$ times current value). (You could probably combine the integrals with a change of variables and possibly make it more numerically stable.)